# ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types after importing with panda and converting to matrix

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm working with a data set (partial picture below), and basically, when I important this data set into python using pandas and convert it to a matrix, it replaces all the blank spaces with nan values.

[image]

In the code, I call this data set A (the data set is actually much larger than this) That to me is fine, because I'm trying to use "np.isnan" command to just remove the nan values since I want to end up plotting the corresponding X-Y coordinates in a scatterplot. However, the isnan function is giving me an error: "TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''" -- I'm not sure how to get around this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('S09-9213-29P Coordinate Data.xlsx', sheetname='ROI 3 Coordinates')
A = df.as_matrix() #Convert excel sheet to matrix
A = np.delete(A, (0),axis=0) #Delete header row

CD8X = A[:,8] #Extract x coordinate from data set
CD8X = CD8X[~np.isnan(CD8X)] #Remove nan values

MCT4X = A[:,10]
MCT4X = MCT4X[~np.isnan(MCT4X)] #Remove nan values
```

By removing the nans, the length of MCT4X should end up being 3 rather than the 4000 it is now (due to all the empty spaces). Thank you for the help!

Comment: Change `~np.isnan` to `pd.notna`.

Comment: @cs95 Thanks for the simple fix! :)